# cordova ios xmlhttprequest seems to cache response

Tags: javascript, ios, caching, cordova, xmlhttprequest

I have a cordova ios app that is making a call using XMLHTTPRequest.  The scenario is that, I log in the first time with correct username/password, app works as expected.  Upon logout which does a few things, I explicitly attempt a login with wrong username/password.  Seems that it is still logging me in.  I've even alerted the response from the server and it is returning the previous response.

I've ready other threads similar to my current situation, however, I've added such lines:

"cache-control :  no-cache"
"cache-control :  max-age=0"
"pragma: no-cache"

But none worked.  Any info would be helpful.  Thanks.

Comment: can you provide your code?

Comment: Hi Dawson.  Thanks for the reply.  here's a snippet of my XMLHTTPRequest call:  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.open(method,url,false);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encode(accessInfo) );
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/xml,application/atom+xml");
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/atom+xml");

Comment: Just did some googleing and found a lot of people are using a cache busting method of appending a random `get` variable or the timestamp as a `get` variable, something like this: `url + "?v=" + Math.random()` or better in my opinion: `url + "?t=" + (new Date()).getTime()`

Comment: Hi Dawson.  I tried that too.  on my variable 'url', I did this: var n = new Date().getTime();  then on next line var url = baseurl + "?param=" + n.  but still the same use case result.  I'm getting our server admin to see if there's a way to turn off some sort of session or cookie on server side.  it's a long shot but I'm running out of ideas here.  I've even simplified the login logic where instead of calling a function to do the login upon "button push", I just perform the xmlhttprequest connection directly to remove any other point of error.

Comment: Are you able to use jQuery? Asking because I have an API connector object that I wrote for this type of thing that has always worked for me, but it's tied in with jquery. If that is possible, I will share the code with you.

Comment: Hi Dawson.  I should be able to use JQuery.  I'd really appreciate it if you can share this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that has been used many times, though it relies on jQuery:

```
var api = {
    connection: {
        baseUrl: '',
        apiUrl: ''
    },
    initialize: function() {
        api.setupAjaxDefaults();
    },
    setupAjaxDefaults: function() {
        var headers = {
            'Accept': "application/json; encoding='utf-8'",
            'Content-Type': "application/json; encoding='utf-8'"
        };
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: headers,
            dataType: 'json',
            crossDomain: true
        });
    },
    ajaxPost: function(methodName, data, successCallback, errorCallback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: api.connection.baseUrl + api.connection.apiUrl + methodName,
            data: data,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(result, status, xhr) {
                if ($.isFunction(successCallback)) {
                    successCallback(result);
                }
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                if ($.isFunction(errorCallback)) {
                    errorCallback();
                }
                else {
                    api.defaultErrorCallback(textStatus);
                }
            }
        });
    },
    ajaxGet: function(methodName, data, successCallback, errorCallback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: api.connection.baseUrl + api.connection.apiUrl + methodName,
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(result, status, xhr) {
                if ($.isFunction(successCallback)) {
                    successCallback(result);
                }
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                if ($.isFunction(errorCallback)) {
                    errorCallback();
                }
                else {
                    api.defaultErrorCallback(textStatus);
                }
            }
        });
    },
    ajaxGetCached: function(methodName, data, successCallback, errorCallback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: api.connection.baseUrl + api.connection.apiUrl + methodName,
            data: data,
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(result, status, xhr) {
                if ($.isFunction(successCallback)) {
                    successCallback(result);
                }
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                if ($.isFunction(errorCallback)) {
                    errorCallback();
                }
                else {
                    api.defaultErrorCallback(textStatus);
                }
            }
        });
    },
    defaultErrorCallback: function(errorMsg) {
        //alert('an api error occurred: ' + errorMsg);
    }
};
```

Start by filling in the `connection` object. `baseUrl` is `http(s)://mydomain.tdl` and `apiUrl` is for versioning or segmenting your API, if not needed set it to `/` otherwise use as `/myApiv1/`.

If you need `BaiscAuth` add `username: someuser` and `password: plaintextpassword` to the `ajaxSetup` object in the method `setupAjaxDefaults`.

Once your application fires the `deviceready` event call `api.initialize();`

Then to make uncached requests use:

```
api.ajaxGet('someEndpoint', { some: param, someother: data }, aSuccessCallbackFn, optionalFailureCallbackFn);
```